# Refer an iframe from the next iframe of the same document

Tags: iframe, same-origin-policy, postmessage

I have two iframes (*iframe1* and *iframe2*) from the same domain, which are hosted in a document from different domain. How can i refer *iframe1* from *iframe2*, so that they can communicate through *postMessage()*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer it myself, `postMessage()` is ideal for communication between an iframe and its parent document. But in my case it would be better to use `sessionStorage` for communication between the iframes from the same origin.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage

Answer (score 0):

The description and examples of usage of the HTML5 postMessage method are pretty [well documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage). If you are using jQuery you might also find the [following plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/) very useful as it abstracts much of the necessary code.

Comment: @sawren, yes, if both frames are hosted on the same domain as well as the parent.

Comment: can an iframe refer to the next iframe through *parent.frames[x]* ?

Comment: how to prevent browser from adding custom frameset around the actual document of iframe